# Run python subprocess in background with log output

Tags: python, subprocess

First off: yes, I already checked the documentation for subprocesses. I was not able to find a solution for my problem, thats why I'm now posting here.

My code:

```
import os
import subprocess
import shlex

processname = '/usr/bin/python3.5 /usr/bin/asphalt run config.yml'

print("checking")
def proc_check(command):
    for line in os.popen("ps xwa"):
        fields = line.split()
        pid = fields[0]
        process = fields[4]

        if len(fields) == 8:
            process = fields[4] + " " + fields[5] + " " + fields [6] + " " + fields[7]

        if command == process:
            # Kill the Process. Change signal.SIGHUP to signal.SIGKILL if you like
            os.kill(int(pid), signal.SIGKILL)

            # Do something else here
            print("Killed Process")
            print(pid)
            print(process)
            return True
    return False

if proc_check(processname):
    print("all good")
else:
    with open('apiServer.log', 'w') as apiLog:
        with open('apiServer.err', 'w') as errLog:
            command = "cd /root/ProjectAthena/APIServer/" \
                      "&& . ./venv/bin/activate " \
                      "&& PYTHONPATH=. asphalt run /root/ProjectAthena/APIServer/config.yml"
            ApiHelp = subprocess.Popen(command, stderr=errLog,stdout=apiLog, shell=True)
            print("subprocces spawned!")
            ApiHelp.communicate()
```

I want to run a server to supply a API to another program. As the server has to run all the time (with output to a file) I used a function to check if my asphalt server is already running.

If it is: do nothing.
If it is not: start it.
My console tells me that the process was started but sadly it does not work or show up with `ps aux`.

The problem I came across while reading through the existing questions was that my program is always running, therefore there will be no EOF to listen on. Everything else I've tried blocked my process.

Maybe I need to use Threads (?). Sadly I'm not that familiar with Threads so any snipped would be awesome!

Any help here is very much appreciated!

thanks,

marvin/Nop0x

Comment: why u cant use cronjob

Comment: could you end your background task get the data and re run it? so you get the EOF

Comment: AbdulRazak - I want to deploy my program as a package, thats why I want to run the server inside it.
@WhatsThePoint I can't end the background task, as it needs to be always on for my main program to work.

Comment: Please check the answer to this one. It may answer your question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62568597/how-to-run-python-subprocess-with-real-time-output