# How to run python subprocess with real-time output?

Tags: python, subprocess, output, real-time

When I run a shell command in Python it does not show the output until the command is finished. the script that I run takes a few hours to finish and I'd like to see the progress while it is running.
How can I have python run it and show the outputs in real-time?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following function to run your code. In this example, I want to run an R script with two arguments. You can replace cmd with any other shell command.

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def run(command):
    process = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True)
    while True:
        line = process.stdout.readline().rstrip()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line)

cmd = f"Rscript {script_path} {arg1} {arg2}"
run(cmd)
```